# Why do I need to cast?

Tags: java, casting

In the following code snippet, I am not very clear about the usefulness of

```
Product other = (Product)obj;
```

It seems to me that it is redundant. Can we just remove this one, and change "return this.id==other.id" to "return this.id == obj.id"?

```
public class Product{
  String description;
  double price;
  int id;

  public Product(String d, double p, int i){
    description = d;
    price = p;
    id = i;
  }

  public boolean equals(Object obj){
    if(!(obj instanceof Product){
      return false;
    }
    Product other = (Product)obj;
    return this.id == other.id;
  }

  public int hashcode(){
    return id;
  }

  public String toString(){
    return id + " "+description;
  } 
}
```

Comment: Why don't you try it and see what happens?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea there is that you need to tell the language to treat `other` as a `Product`. Until you do, it only sees it as an `Object`, which doesn't have an `id` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't cast the Object obj to a Product, you cannot access the id field. That is why, there is a check in front. If it is not of type Product than return false...

cheers

Answer (score 1):

An `Object` object doesn't have an `id` field, so you can't access such a field, that's why you cast it to `Product` (also valid - `((Product)obj).id` - you access the id of the casted obj). Also, since you want to override the `equals` method, you have to get an object of the same class (`Object`) as the original method.

Answer (score 1):

It might as well be written as:

`return this.id == ((Product)other).id;`

The object would not have the property "id" if you dont type cast it to Product and hence you could not check the id to be the same. So typecasting the object to Product.

Answer (score 0):

That wouldn't work because you are comparing the id properties of the two objects which are Products.